# Toplevel in Tkinter: Prevent Two Windows from Opening

Tags: python, tkinter

Say I have some simple code, like this:

```
from Tkinter import *
root = Tk()
app = Toplevel(root)
app.mainloop()
```

This opens two windows: the `Toplevel(root)` window and the `Tk()` window.

Is it possible to avoid the `Tk()` window (`root`) from opening? If so, how? I only want the toplevel. I want this to happen because I am making a program that will have multiple windows opening, which are all `Toplevel`'s of the `root`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The [`withdraw()`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/wm.htm#Tkinter.Wm.withdraw-method) method removes the window from the screen.
The [`iconify()`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/wm.htm#Tkinter.Wm.iconify-method) method minimizes the window, or turns it into an icon.
The [`deiconify()`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/wm.htm#Tkinter.Wm.deiconify-method) method will redraw the window, and/or activate it.

If you choose `withdraw()`, make sure you've considered a new way to exit the program before testing.
e.g.

```
from Tkinter import * # tkinter in Python 3

root = Tk()
root.withdraw()

top = Toplevel(root)
top.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", root.destroy)

but = Button(top, text='deiconify')
but['command'] = root.deiconify
but.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

The [`protocol()`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/wm.htm#Tkinter.Wm.protocol-method) method can be used to register a function that will be called when the
*Toplevel window's* close button is pressed. In this case we can use [`destroy()`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.destroy-method) to exit.