# omitting Toplevel's parent argument

Tags: python, tkinter

I was checking out `Toplevel` of tkinter. From what I've seen from [effbot](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/toplevel.htm) I can omit its parent argument.

1-  When I only use Toplevel itself (commenting out root), it creates its own parent I believe since two windows appear and only destroys one after clicking button.

2- If I don't comment out `Tk()`, it works fine. Two windows, one root - one toplevel and destroys toplevel.

3- If I interchange root and toplevel, first toplevel creates two again(like in first case), then root will create another so three windows will appear and only toplevel gets destroyed.

```
import tkinter as tk

#root = tk.Tk()
top = tk.Toplevel()

#root.title("Foo")
top.title("Bar")
top.geometry("300x100")

tk.Button(top, text = "Destroy", command=top.destroy).pack()

top.mainloop()
```

Question is, is there a way to create toplevel before `Tk()` and get only one window or access its parent and destroy it?

p.s. I found these two questions [Toplevel in Tkinter: Prevent Two Windows from Opening](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15046498/toplevel-in-tkinter-prevent-two-windows-from-opening) &&  [tkinter child window opens two windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18798761/tkinter-child-window-opens-two-windows). First question is in 2nd case which is not what I want, and second question has no answer yet and his problem kind of not reproducable.

Also, I tried to get its master value -to destroy is manually- like this but seems like that value is not stored in dictionary where options are stored.

```
btn = tk.Button(top, text = "Destroy", command=top.destroy)
btn.pack()

print (btn["text"])
>>> Destroy
print (btn["master"])
>>>  _tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-master"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not that `Toplevel` creates it's own parent, any widget will create a root window if you don't create one first. There simply must be a root window before any other widget can exist -- that's why it's called a *root* window. So, to answer your specific question, no, there is no way to create an instance of `Toplevel` without creating a root window first.